# How can I receive return data from a HTML popup on Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-html

I am working on a plugin that launches a WebView to carry out some auth verification. Using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin, it works fine on Android and iOS once I call the `runJavascriptReturningResult` function. It returns the `document.getElementById('return').innerText` and then I parse the result. But on Flutter web, the [webview_flutter_web](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter_web) does not currently support `runJavascriptReturningResult`, so it throws a platform error once invoked.

I tried using an HTML Popup, but I don't know how to extract the return data before the popup closes.

My implementation for the popup is like this:

```
html.WindowBase _popup = html.window.open(url, name,'left=100,top=100,width=800,height=600');
if (_popup.closed!) {
  throw("Popups blocked");
}
```

How do I get the return data before the popup closes? Is there another way to do this on Flutter Web?

Comment: How should auth verification be executed? Javascript API details?

Comment: @user18309290 The auth screen is a webpage online. Once the URL loads the user carries out necessary things. Then once complete, the response is found in the `document.getElementById('return').innerText`.

Comment: @user18309290 The API is not Javascript. The issue to be able to extract the `document.getElementById('return').innerText` from the loaded webpage on Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to listen to `onMessage`. Then get the event data from it.

```
  html.window.open(url!, 'new tab');

  html.window.onMessage.listen((event) async {
    log(event.data.toString()); // Prints out the Message
   
  });
```

Comment: How onMessage helps to use document.getElementById('return').innerText?

Comment: @roosi on message picks anything that is sent from the site. Btw the `return` is sent

Answer (score 0):

Maybe listening [beforeunload](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/Window/beforeUnloadEvent-constant.html) event on the new window and getting the return value before it closes.

Comment: listening to `beforeunload` didn't work